# Limit $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)(x+a_2)...(x+a_n)} - x$ =?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

What is the limit of $ f(x) = \sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)(x+a_2)...(x+a_n)} - x$ when $x$ goes to plus infinity? The number $n$ is fixed and $a_i$ are some constants.

All I know is the answer:
$(a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n) / n$

I figured out that I can limit the root from above with the arithmetic mean. And this gives me some nice expression as an upper limit. But OK... this only proves the limit is $\leq (a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n) / n$.

But how do I limit it from below with the same value. I tried using the harmonic mean but it seems it does not lead me to anything nice. So... any ideas?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591903/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/922452/42969

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me read through these.

Comment: I think this answer might be closest to what I need. Trying to rework it a bit for my exact case. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/592089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdot (x+a_n)=x^n+ b x^{n-1}+\mathcal{O}(x^{n-2})$$
Where $b=a_1+a_2+\dots +a_n$, and 
$$\sqrt[n]{x^n+bx^{n-1}+\mathcal{O}(x^{n-2})}=\left(x^n+bx^{n-1}+\mathcal{O}(x^{n-2})\right)^{1/n}=x \left(1+bx^{-1} +\mathcal{O}(x^{-2})\right)^{1/n}$$
Now, we can use the first order Taylor approximation of $(1+x)^q$ around $x=0$ (which is $1+q x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$) to get

$$x \left(1+b +\mathcal{O}(x^{2-n})\right)^{1/n}= x\left(1+\frac{b}{n x} +\mathcal{O}(x^{-2})\right)=x-\frac{b}{n } +\mathcal{O}(x^{-1}).  $$

From this, we can see that the limit is $\frac{b}{n}$.

**A more elementary solution:** Let $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdot (x+a_n)}$, note that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(1+a_1x^{-1})(1+a_2x^{-1})\cdot (1+a_nx^{-1})}=1\tag{1}$$

Note that

$$f(x)-x=\frac{f(x)^n-x^n}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x)^{n-1-k} x^{k}}= \frac{f(x)^n-x^n}{f(x)^{n-1}+f(x)^{n-2}x+\dots+f(x)x^{n-2}+x^{n-1}}$$

The numerator is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ with a leading coefficient of $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$, the denominator is composed of the sum of $n$ terms $f(x)^{n-1-k}x^k$. Divide both by $x^{n-1}$ to get

\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)-x&=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)^n-x^n}{x^{n-1}} \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{f(x)^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}+\frac{f(x)^{n-2}}{x^{n-2}}+\dots+\frac{f(x)}{x}+1}\\
&=(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)\cdot \frac{1}{1+1+\dots+1} \\ &
=\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n}\end{align*}

Comment: I need something simpler. This needs to be solved without Taylor. Assume Taylor is not introduced yet. I am not sure the other answers I was pointed to are much help too. Still looking at them though...

Comment: @peter.petrov: I have added a more elementary solution.

Comment: I think this will do it, I just need to take some time to understand it :) Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, this seems really nice... I think I got it. Thanks a lot for this elementary and detailed proof.

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$ a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdots(x+a_n)} - x\\
&=&\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdots(x+a_n) - x^n}{\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdots(x+a_n)}^{n-1} + \sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdots(x+a_n)}^{n-2}x+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdots(x+a_n)}x^{n-2}+x^{n-1}}\\
&=&\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)+o(\frac1x)}{n+o(\frac1x)}\\
&=&\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+ a_n}{n}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This was my other idea to use $a^n - b^n$ somehow (it's a pretty obvious idea)... but I didn't manage to get to anywhere... Thanks, let me try to understand this proof.

Comment: I don't get the part after the second `=`. OK, in the numerator we have some polynomial of x of degree (n-1) with main coefficient $(a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n)$ But then what...? In the denominator we have something pretty "unpleasant". No? Where does this n in the denominator come from?

Comment: @peter.petrov, divide both num. and den. by $x^{n-1}$.

Comment: Aha... So... I think your idea is the same as the one from `aziiri`, right? It's just written in more details there (in their answer), it seems. Right? But essentially it's the same idea, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, we have $$a^n-b^n = (a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i b^{n-1-i}$$

Hence, we can rewrite the expression as follows
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)\cdots(x+a_n)} - x &= \frac{(x+a_1)\cdots(x+a_n)-x^n}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)\cdots(x+a_n)})^i x^{n-1-i}} \\
\text{divide by } x^{n-1} \text{ above and below} \\
&= \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n + \mathcal{O}(x^-1)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)\cdots(x+a_n)})^i x^{-i}} \\
&= \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n + \mathcal{O}(x^-1)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sqrt[n]{\frac{(x+a_1)\cdots(x+a_n)}{x^n}})^i} \\
&= \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n + \mathcal{O}(x^-1)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sqrt[n]{1+\mathcal{O}(x^{-1})})^i} 
\end{align*}

Now, taking a limit as $x \to \infty$, we get the desired result.